# Automatic templating of Strings in a content control

Tags: wpf, xaml, contentcontrol

I'm having an issue with data templating in content controls. Its a situation ive overcome before with a datatemplateselector but I feel i must be missing something.

Consider this Xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <ContentControl MaxWidth="50" Content="This is a string and it should be wrapped."/>
</Grid>
```

My style is not being applied to to the generated textblock. I suspect it is because the generated textblock is not part of the logical tree. A datatemplate selector fixes this, which is great but I feel it is not the best solution.

Any advice on the most concise flexible way to get around this? I am using .net 4.0

*EDIT: A Datatemplate with DataType={x:Type String} also fixes the issue but it also feels like a hack.*

Comment: The generated `TextBlock` is part of the logical tree(Snoop would confirm that for you), however `ContentControl` just like `ControlTemplate` would be a boundary WPF does not automatically apply implict style's on **unless** the `Style` is defined in your Application scope. If you move your `Style` from `Grid.Resources` to `Application.Resources`, you can see it works fine. For your use case I'd say specifying a DataTemplate with `DataType="{x:Type sys:String}"` is as clean as one could hope for. Not rly sure why you think that's a "hack" since it defines exactly what it does

Comment: ..contd^^. By defining a `DataTemplate` you keep your `Style`'s scope specific to your `ContentControl` and if you chose, you can always use `Style.BasedOn` to derive it from a higher scope `Style` for the same element. I'd prefer this to a `DataTemplateSelector`. My "personal" preference is to use a `DataTemplateSelector` when `DataType` is the same, but I need to use different Visual representations. If the `DataType` itself is different wouldn't really go for a `DataTemplateSelector`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Viv. I had no idea that such boundaries existed. I assume this is a performance concern? Knowing this explains a lot of odd behavior i have observed.

Comment: Your welcome :). I wouldn't say it's performance related since anything derived from `Control` "should?" carry on the implicit Style, however things like `TextBlock` derive from `FrameworkElement` and there are valid cases, you wouldn't want them getting implicitly Styled. Such as say the "Text" within a `Button` getting the `TextBlock` Style applied on it cos of implicit Style. [This is a decent explanation of the same if you wanna have a read.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2009/08/27/implicit-styles-templates-controls-and-frameworkelements.aspx)

Comment: Thankyou again sir. Some great material to get my noggin around here. After 3 years, WPF keeps on surprising me! I would still prefer to be able to implicitly style everything but I agree that the obviousness of  generated frameworkelements would cause headscratching moments.

Comment: you can still implicitly Style your control's. Define the Style within the "boundary"(in other words inside the `DataTemplate`). btw does this answer your question, or is there anything else you're looking for specifically?

Comment: This answered the question. However, I set an implicit button style on a window yesterday and it still affected DatePicker's button. No idea why!

Comment: Can't rly comment without looking at the code. However if your implicit style was targeting a Control(or something deriving from it) than framework element, it will pass thru the boundary.